# Java. String.split(Regex) Парсинг строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, split

Дается строка, которую нужно распарсить на составные части

```
String line = "param1 param2 'param3 param3 param3' param4";
String[] params = line.split("Регулярное выражение");
```

На выходе `params` должен разбиваться по `пробелу` и по `'тексту в кавычках'`:
То есть:

```
param1
param2
param3 param3 param3
param4
```

Я не могу составить подобное регулярное выражение, прошу помочь.
Вот мой вариант, но он не работает так как нужно:

```
String[] params = line.split("[\\s(^'.'$)]");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Еще вариант:

```
String line = "param1 param2 'param3 param3 param3' param4";
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(line.replaceAll("\'", "").split("'?(\\s|$)(?=(([^']*'){2})*[^']*$)'?")));
// [param1, param2, param3 param3 param3, param4]
```

С использованием [apache-commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrTokenizer.html)

```
StrTokenizer tokenizer = new StrTokenizer(line, ' ', '\'');
while(tokenizer.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
}
// param1
// param2
// param3 param3 param3
// param4
```

Последний вариант (честно стырено [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25756010/5694145)):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("((?<=')[^']*(?='(\\s|$)+)|(?<=\\s|^)[^\\s']*(?=\\s|$))").matcher(line);
while ( m.find() ) {
    list.add(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(list);
// [param1, param2, param3 param3 param3, param4]
```

Comment: Не универсально. Если добавить еще param3 то не получается: param1 param2 'param3 param3 param3 param3' param4

Comment: Это выражение не распарсит одинарную кавычку, две кавычки подряд, т.е. то, что можно считать ошибкой синтаксиса исходного выражения. Параметров можно добавлять сколько угодно.

Comment: Действительно.... Видимо я в первый раз как то не верно ввел. Спасибо. буду разбираться в вашем регулярном выражении!

Comment: Нет все-таки регулярка не очень хорошая. Она не убирает кавычку в начале строки. Метод, который предложил  @Arsenicum - матчить совпадения параметров, а не разделители - изначально более правильный. Поправил ответ. разбирать регулярки [удобно тут.](https://regex101.com/r/bQ1bR2/1)

Comment: метод Arsenicum оставляет кавычки. Этот метод оставляет одну кавычку в начале строки. Постараюсь тогда сам составить подходящую рег.

Comment: Небольшая избыточность в коде иной раз лучше магии в регулярке. Добавил последний вариант. А ваша, кстати, [матчит пробел после кавычки](https://regex101.com/r/bQ1bR2/2). Так можно IndexOfBound или NPE получить :)

Answer (score 5):

Попробуйте такой код:

```
String line = "param1 param2 'param3 param3 param3' param4";

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^\']\\S*|\'.+?\')\\s*").matcher(line);
while (m.find())
    list.add(m.group(1).replaceAll("'", ""));

System.out.println(list);
```

В итоге получится: `[param1, param2, param3 param3 param3, param4]`

Смотрим группу без кавычек `[^\']\\S*` или группу с кавычками `\'.+?\'`.

Comment: Доработал Ваш вариант ((?<=').+?(?='))|([^\']\\S*)\\s* теперь как нужно)

Comment: @CJ1, если изменить строчку на `list.add(m.group(1).replaceAll("'", ""));`, то у вас будет результат без одиночных кавычек.